# PHP Ajax GET method does not fire

Tags: php, ajax, get

I have problem passing 2 parameters using php/ajax/mysql.

Not able to trace out the problem

Here is Ajax code

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myonoffswitch').click(function(){
var myonoffswitch=$('#myonoffswitch').val();
if ($("#myonoffswitch:checked").length == 0)
{
var a=myonoffswitch;
}
else
{
var a="off";
}

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "process.php",
data: "ps="+a ,
success: function(html){
$("#display").html(html).show();
}
});

});
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){
$(".cb-enable").click(function(){
var parent = $(this).parents('.switch');
$('.cb-disable',parent).removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
$('.checkbox',parent).attr('checked', true);
});
$(".cb-disable").click(function(){
var parent = $(this).parents('.switch');
$('.cb-enable',parent).removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
$('.checkbox',parent).attr('checked', false);
});
});
</script>
```

PHP :

```
$k=1; 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$id = $row['ID'];   
$ps = $row['Status'];

    echo "<div class=\"onoffswitch\">\n";
        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"$k\" class=\"onoffswitch-checkbox\" id=\"$k\"\n";
        if($ps=="1") {
            echo "checked ";
        }
        echo ">";
        echo "<label class=\"onoffswitch-label\" for=\"$k\">\n";
        echo "  <div class=\"onoffswitch-inner\"></div>\n";
        echo "  <div class=\"onoffswitch-switch\"></div>\n";
        echo "</label>\n";
    echo "</div>\n";
    $k++;
}
```

process .php is similar to below :

$ps=$_POS['ps'];
$id=$_POS['id'];

//mysql_query("UPDATE Tbl set Status='$ps' where ID=$id"); // does not work

mysql_query("UPDATE Tbl set Status='$ps' where ID=1");

code updated and working when passing only 1 argument/parameter.

POST or GET method will be ok. Any help please ?

Comment: Edit your question instead of writing a comment

Comment: Please make sure your code is properly indented, otherwise it's just unreadable

Comment: are you getting error in console??

Comment: I don't know if you can pass value using URL in ajax function. If its wrong then try using `data` in ajax call

Comment: also try making this `url: "process.php?ps="+a+"&id="+id;` to `url: "process.php?ps="+a+"&id="+id,` remove `;` and add `,`

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of `echo` statements inside you PHP file.

Change your code to this. and tell me if it works

```
$k = 1;

$content = null;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) or die ("<p>DB Erroe!!!</p>")) {
    $id = $row['ID'];
    $ps = $row['Status'];

    $content .= "<div class=\"onoffswitch\">\n";
    $content .= "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"$k\" class=\"onoffswitch-checkbox\" id=\"$k\"\n";
    if ($ps == "1") {
        echo "checked ";
    }
    $content .= ">";
    $content .= "<label class=\"onoffswitch-label\" for=\"$k\">\n";
    $content .= "  <div class=\"onoffswitch-inner\"></div>\n";
    $content .= "  <div class=\"onoffswitch-switch\"></div>\n";
    $content .= "</label>\n";
    $content .= "</div>\n";
    $k++;
}

echo $content;
```

Comment: so it means you have no results returned by `mysqli_fetch_array($result)` ... first check that query is right and it is executing

Comment: sorry i mean after click on any checkbox nothing happens. DB does not affect any row.

Answer (score 0):

```
var send='{"ps":"'+a+'","id":"'+id+'"}';
var obj=JSON.parse(send);
$.ajax({
type: "GET", 
url: "process.php",
data: obj,
success: function(html){
$("#display").html(html).show();
}
});
```

Comment: tried that but does not work.  even i try passing only 1 argument  using     data: "ps="+a

Comment: what are errors you are getting in console.. Because I think you should use JSON to send data.. Tell me error in colsole.. and I will give you json method

Comment: i am trying to implement this [link](http://www.freezecoders.com/2013/05/store-value-from-onoff-button-in-mysql-database-using-php-ajax.html)

Comment: Change `type: "POST",` if you are using post method

Comment: are you using firebug to track your ajax request?

Comment: @reenleedr nothing is working even after passing only one parameter

Comment: if you are using chrome browser. right click->inspect element and on the top right corner tell if errors are there or not? error are in red circle.

Comment: add `alert('hello');` after `$("#display").html(html).show();` to see if ajax is working or not..

Comment: no error in inspect element window. Alert also does not work. anywy i managed to work with only 1 argument "ps="+a using my existing code, now the problem is with multiple checkbox

Comment: i think i have to assign id somehere in ajax code 
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
but where

Answer (score 0):

Do not, I repeat, DO NOT, use the mysql_* interface. Switch to mysqli or PDO.  It is deprecated and gone in the latest PHP release.  And *especially* do not mix them!  It won't work!